# How to get ItkImage Data in java wrapper

Tags: java, word-wrap, itk

I use Java wrapper to load Dicom image, but i dont know how to get the array of bytes in the image
I used this code

```
String _FileName="D:\\Patient.dcm";
org.itk.simple.ImageFileReader reader = new org.itk.simple.ImageFileReader() ;
reader.setFileName(_FileName) ;
Image img = reader.execute ( ) ;
SWIGTYPE_p_signed_char _p1 = img.getBufferAsInt8();
```

It's my first time to use java so i dont know how to convert _p1 to the array,Is there any swig interface class i should use to convert _p1 to java array?or should i use a type of itk array?

**EDIT:**

In the old version they used Pixelcontainer to get the array but they removed it in the recent versions